# string contains() method return false even if the strings are matching

Tags: java, selenium

getText is: management
company //management and company are in different line
and colName is management company

Code: Its not returning true

```
   for(int j=0;j<allHeader.size();j++) {System.out.println(allHeader.get(j).getText().trim().toLowerCase()+"::"+colName.trim().toLowerCase());
                  if(allHeader.get(j).getText().trim().toLowerCase().contains(colName.trim().toLowerCase())){
                      System.out.println("true");
                      colNum=j+1;
                  }
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to match 2 strings ignoring the newline and space characters. You can remove the white space characters first and then check equality (or contains):-

```
String getText = "management\ncompany";
String colName = "management company";
boolean match = getText.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
        .equalsIgnoreCase(colName.replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
System.out.println(match);
```

Or a less flexible way would be to replace the newline with a space:-

```
boolean match = getText.replaceAll("\n", " ").equalsIgnoreCase(colName);
```

Output:-

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

what do u mean by management and company are in different line ?

its not working coz your getText() returns something like "management \n company" while you are checking for "management company" so its returning false coz it cannot find exact string "management company"

u can replace \n and then test it